# Why does my privoxy log show lots of requests to updateservice.sonic.com/Ping.asp?

Tags: internet, proxy, isp

I installed privoxy as a transparent proxy on a gateway machine, and I have Sonic for an ISP. I'm seeing a lot of requests to http://updateservice.sonic.com/Ping.asp when I'm browsing random pages.

Does anybody know what that's about?

I have an unconfirmed guess that this is some sort of Microsoft CDN solution so they don't have to have a server cluster somewhere with a few Gbps of bandwidth to answer update queries every 10 minutes for every computer on the planet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the [Sonic update manager](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/sonic-update-manager/). You can remove it if you don't want its functionality.